# Share Excel cell value in a range

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible in Excel to do something like this?

Column A is reserved for checking particular items (by typing X). In column B, there are names of sets and in column C particular books. In case the user checks at least one book in a set, the whole set should be checked.

It would be pretty simple, if there was a single "root" cell, from which others would simply get reference. The problem is, the user can check any of the cells of a set, which would then make circular reference.

I have not used macros so far, so I am total newbie in this problematique.

Comment: You will have a better experience here if you demonstrate you have made some kind of effort, and ask a question when you get stuck. As a suggestion of where to start, use the macro recorder to emulate what you want to happen in code. Since you are new to VBA, this will give you some idea of how things work under the hood. Good luck!

Comment: The reason, why I asked is to prevent being stuck unnecessarily. I just wanted a simple "Yes, it is possible" or "No, it is not possible". I didn't want to waste my time trying something, that cannot be achieved... Does it really take so much to answer a simple question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following event macro will monitor changes in column **A**.  If an "X" has been entered in column **A**, the macro picks up the set name from column **B** and looks for other instances of this set name in column **B**.  If found, an "X" is placed in column **A**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, nB As Long, B As Range, r As Range
    Dim v As String
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value <> "X" Then Exit Sub
    nB = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set B = Range("B1:B" & nB)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    v = Target.Offset(0, 1).Text
    For Each r In B
        If r.Text = v Then
            r.Offset(0, -1).Value = "X"
        End If
    Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Update this post if you have further questions.